# Wordpress plugin with classes, namespaces and psr-0 autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, wordpress, psr-0

I'm pretty new at this Wordpress thingy and I've now made my own theme and would like to create a plugin that handles my slideshow.

(I have to teach this for some pupils later on, so I cannot just use an existing plugin)

I have implemented the autoloader from http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0 at the bottom and it works fine.

I can call all the methods in my class and everything, so thats fine. **Here's the actual question:**

When the

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('vendor\Keystroke\KeystrokeSlider', 'install'));
```

is called, then it runs the method

```
class KeystrokeSlider{

    const VERSION = '1.0.0';

    static public function install(){
         global $wpdb;

         $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

         $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'ks_albums';
         $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (
             id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
             created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY  (id)
         ) $charset_collate;";

         self::upgrade();

         dbDelta($sql);

         add_option('keystroke_slider_version', self::VERSION);
    }
}
```

but the dbDelta() is an undefined function. I could see that it was trying to set the namespace in front of the function (I don't know why, since it's not at class method, but a function, right?). Anyway I've tried calling it like this

```
\dbDelta()
```

That seems to be working, but It still can't find the function. Can I manually require the dbDelta in the class or is there something else wrong?

Sorry for the very long question...

Ulrik McArdle

Comment: If I recall it right, there were few bugs with `dbDelta`. You should use simple query function instead.

Comment: According to the manual: you should require the upgrade class in order to use it `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );`. Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table

Comment: I'm so stupid... Thank you... I deleted it, as I put in my own upgrade method in my class and I totally overlooked, that it was requiring an wp-admin file...

Comment: May I write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WP manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) in order to use the `dbDelta` function you first need to include the `upgrade` file which contains that function.

Therefore, adding the following line of code above `dbDelta($sql)` should fix the problem:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
```